# hash of lubuntu-14.04.1- desktop-amd64.iso

Tags: lubuntu, hash

I can not find what the hash of Lubuntu-desktop-14.04.1- amd64.iso is.

<sup>Original language commented out, but still there</sup>

Comment: https://translate.google.se/?hl=en&tab=wT#auto/en/

Comment: Please post in English

Answer (score 1):

The [CD images repository](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/) also includes a file with all the hashes. The `MD5SUMS` file contains:

```
d3181e58212e62b6656c8cf5f9b922a7 *lubuntu-14.04-alternate-amd64+mac.iso
dc6d7ee644b825cae63f59c91d707852 *lubuntu-14.04-alternate-amd64.iso
35a41aa73bfe3c47a57d49a5182e9891 *lubuntu-14.04-alternate-i386.iso
4d9e511daf41dbc44f4506958f0e70f9 *lubuntu-14.04-alternate-powerpc.iso
2cfdcc5162f70515f4b59c80a142e36b *lubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso
c138cedb0f72cbd115c55e3f14a98f5e *lubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
b0d1c58c8515ab40382d01f59655ba85 *lubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
2ca3784e4575214c13c85effca9dd4ae *lubuntu-14.04-desktop-powerpc.iso
2bf5abe48007c247ec214ec4e7681558 *lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-amd64+mac.iso
a5f97cd6a9f171c70cf816de8728f13b *lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso
a7c153f1101fb8a181ccda01a448ffd1 *lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-i386.iso
69d8c99a4724ddb281c9076fd9c8d771 *lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-powerpc.iso
ebb98a27efd717fee62077e2d492c704 *lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64+mac.iso
4a6555869fbbe11fa6a17f83be046455 *lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
281fc36d625f7ca0704297b3b811fa66 *lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
0af2df006d5220832f5a713bd9ba9d82 *lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-powerpc.iso
```

So the MD5 hash of the 14.04.1 amd64 desktop image is `4a6555869fbbe11fa6a17f83be046455`. This file is more reliable than the community help site, which has been known to be out-of-date before. There's also the [SHA1SUMS file](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/SHA1SUMS) with SHA1 hashes.

Comment: @TommasoCentrone Uh, Tim posted the other answer (with c138... as the hash).

Comment: Note this isn't a HTTPS connection and that in order to truly verify this (to ensure there's no MITM attack), you also need to check the GPG signature of the file too.

Comment: @Oli true. This was noted in the bug - the dev said this wasn't something they could do anything about.

Answer (score 0):

All ubuntu hashes can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

Lubuntu 14.04.1 amd 64 is the following:

```
c138cedb0f72cbd115c55e3f14a98f5e
```

Comment: 14.04**.1** isn't on that list.

Comment: I assumed they just updated the 14.04 one.